# SAPUI5 Popup Dialog Button Dynamic Visibility

Tags: sapui5

I've a SAPUI5 popup dialog which has several buttons in the footer section of the popup.

I need to dynamically set the visibility of a button in the popup based on a value of a model property. Is there any way to do that.

```
that.oNewAppointmentDialog = new Dialog({
                    title: "{i18n>CreatePopupTitle}",
                    content: [
                        sap.ui.xmlfragment("CreateFrag", "proj.view.fragments.AssignmentCreate", this)
                    ],
                        buttons: [ 
                             new Button({
                                text: "{i18n>CreatePopupText}",
                                type: "Ghost",
                                press: function () {

                                }
                            }),
                             new Button({
                                text: "{i18n>CreatePopupClearButton}",
                                type: "Ghost",
                                press: function () {

                                }
                            }),
                             new Button({
                                text: "{i18n>CloseButton}",
                                press: function () {
                                    // Close Button Click Event
                                    that.oNewAppointmentDialog.close();
                                }
                            })
                            ]

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [visible](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/setVisible) property of the [sap.m.Button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button):

```
...
  new Button({
    text: "{i18n>CreatePopupText}",
    visible: "{yourModel>TrueOrFalse}"
  });
...
```

in case the attribute `TrueOrFalse` of `yourModel` is not a Boolean then use a [formatter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html):

```
...
  new Button({
    text: "{i18n>yourButtonText}",
    visible: {
      path: "yourModel>TrueOrFalse",
      formatter: function(sArgument) {
        return yourApp.model.formatter.yourMethod(sArgument);
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: How to use a formatter in this scenario. I've used formatters only in xml views